# How to add ID to magento products

Tags: class, magento, templates, e-commerce

I'm trying to add some id to the span where in bundle product Magento shows all the bundled products.

[see snapshot](http://nikos.x25.pl/allegro/images/bundledproduct.jpg)

So I would like to change input id from bundle-option-x-qty-input to bundle-produkt-sku or something like this. 
I need to have a static id for added products. Now id is dynamically changed by adding a next number bundle-option-1-qty-input, bundle-option-2-qty-input, etc.

I need to know the id of those products cos I want to made some JavaScript code to control amount of this product. Anyone know where is a template file edit or where do I need to add some code?
Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to debug template path is by using  [Magento Template Path Hints](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-template-path-hints-magento)

Go to System -> Configuration In the top left there is a box named “Current Configuration Scope: “ which has a drop down. From that drop down, choose your store view name. By default it is last option in the drop down i.e Default Store View option. After this go to Advanced -> Developer->Debug And here make Template Path Hints = Yes

See

> Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_*
>
> /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php